# how to scrape video media with scrapy or other python's libraries?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, xmlhttprequest, playwright

Concretely I want to extract videos from this website: [equidia](https://www.equidia.fr/courses/2022-07-31/R1/C1). The first problem is when I launch `scrapy shell  https://www.equidia.fr/courses/2022-07-31/R1/C1 -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"`. I inspected with `view(response)` and notice the container of the video exists. I can click on play but there is no flow, so no video to extract. I guess the spider cannot be more able than I do in the web browser during inspection.

UPDATE:
Thanks to palpitus_on_fire I checked more the `XHR` type requests while I only concentrated on `media` type.

The XHR request I am interested about is: `https://equidia-vodce-p-api.hexaglobe.net/video/info/20220731_35186008_00000HR/01NdvIX6xNbihxxc3U52RDBX9novEE47lA1ZmEDw/0b94eb69d04aa18ca33ba5e8767b1a85264c35b6acefc8bfbd7eabb5e259cf2c/1659574478`

It returns a response json file:

```
{
"mp4": {
    "240": "https://private4-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/0bee7ff9bce79419fb27bac012c5d090/62e904dc/equidia_2752987/videos/240p_full_mp4/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523-240p_full_mp4.mp4?v=0",
    "360": "https://private3-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/7c53dc70ae5cc46d7e2c9d43e3dfc685/62e904dc/equidia_2752987/videos/360p_full_mp4/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523-360p_full_mp4.mp4?v=0",
    "480": "https://private3-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/4261c5bd7b48595535710e1dc34e8f93/62e904dc/equidia_2752987/videos/480p_full_mp4/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523-480p_full_mp4.mp4?v=0",
    "540": "https://private3-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/d40592e39e27931f20245edde9f30152/62e904dc/equidia_2752987/videos/540p_full_mp4/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523-540p_full_mp4.mp4?v=0",
    "720": "https://private8-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/9cb5a24a43a8d22d27e73b164020894d/62e904dc/equidia_2752987/videos/720p_full_mp4/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523-720p_full_mp4.mp4?v=0"
    }
"hls": "https://private3-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/6abf08b12203c84390a01fc4de65a4d5/62e904dc/equidia_2752987/videos/hls/63/03/S506303/V556523/playlist.m3u8?v=1",
"master": "https://private8-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/6830b3a5039eef57f844bb08cd252584/62e904dc/equidia_2752987/videos/master/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523.mp4?v=0"
}
```

`"720": "https://private8-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/9cb5a24a43a8d22d27e73b164020894d/62e904dc/equidia_2752987/videos/720p_full_mp4/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523-720p_full_mp4.mp4?v=0"` contains the video and the resolution I want.

Two main problems now:

1. How to obtain `XHR` request and precisely the one starting with `equidia-vodce-p-api.hexaglobe.net` ? The popular solutions are to use webtesters like `selenium` or `playwright` but I know none of them.
2. How to integrate it in a scrapy spider ?

If it is possible I would like to get a code of this form:

```
class VideoPageScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_urls = ['https://www.equidia.fr/courses/2022-07-31/R1/C1']
    def parse(self, response):
        # code to catch the XHR request desired
        urlvideo = 'https://private8-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/9cb5a24a43a8d22d27e73b164020894d/62e904dc/equidia_2752987/videos/720p_full_mp4/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523-720p_full_mp4.mp4?v=0'
       yield scrapy.Request(url=urlvideo, callback=self.obtainvideo)
    def obtainvideo(self, response):
        with #open('/home/avy/binary.mp4', returns'wb') as wfile:
            wfile.write(response.body)
```

---

UPDATES

POSSIBILITY TO GENERATE XHR'S URL ?

Looking at the developement tool of Firefox I am trying to get how the desired XHR request is done.

[image: Development tool in browser]

The script [main.d685b66f8277bab3376b.js](https://www.equidia.fr/main.d685b66f8277bab3376b.js) produce the elements to make the XHR's url (at line 1761 as far as I understand).

```
Object { endpoint: "https://equidia-vodce-p-api.hexaglobe.net/video/info", publicKey: "01NdvIX6xNbihxxc3U52RDBX9novEE47lA1ZmEDw", hash: "c79502b086116f30262dfbf7675225dc1c8bfb4c144df09da9a34b9106fccd39", expiresAt: "1659608062" }
```

Then `https://www.equidia.fr/polyfills.de328f7d13aac150968d.js` initiates a fecth with the XHR's url.

Do you think there is a way to get a generated object based on the script as shown above in order to make the desired XHR request ?

APPENDICE WITH PLAYWRIGHT TRY (headless browser)

I found a library that could be able to obtain the `XHR` requests I am looking for. [`playwright`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/library) is a webtester and it is compatible with `scrapy` with [`scrapy-playwright`](https://scrapeops.io/python-scrapy-playbook/scrapy-playwright/).

Inspired by [those examples](https://www.zenrows.com/blog/web-scraping-intercepting-xhr-requests#use-case-nseindiacom), I tried the following code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
url = 'https://www.equidia.fr/courses/2022-07-31/R1/C1'
with sync_playwright() as p:
    def handle_response(response):
        # the endpoint we are insterested in 
        if ("equidia-vodce-p-api" in response.url):
            item = response.json()['mp4']
            print(item)
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.on("response", handle_response)
    page.goto(url, wait_until="networkidle", timeout=900000)
    page.context.close()
    browser.close()
    
Exception in callback SyncBase._sync.<locals>.callback(<Task finishe...t responses')>) at /home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_sync_base.py:104
handle: <Handle SyncBase._sync.<locals>.callback(<Task finishe...t responses')>) at /home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_sync_base.py:104>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_sync_base.py", line 105, in callback
    g_self.switch()
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_browser_context.py", line 124, in <lambda>
    lambda params: self._on_response(
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_browser_context.py", line 396, in _on_response
    page.emit(Page.Events.Response, response)
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyee/base.py", line 176, in emit
    handled = self._call_handlers(event, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyee/base.py", line 154, in _call_handlers
    self._emit_run(f, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyee/asyncio.py", line 50, in _emit_run
    self.emit("error", exc)
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyee/base.py", line 179, in emit
    self._emit_handle_potential_error(event, args[0] if args else None)
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyee/base.py", line 139, in _emit_handle_potential_error
    raise error
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyee/asyncio.py", line 48, in _emit_run
    coro: Any = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_impl_to_api_mapping.py", line 88, in wrapper_func
    return handler(
  File "<input>", line 7, in handle_response
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/sync_api/_generated.py", line 601, in json
    self._sync("response.json", self._impl_obj.json())
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_sync_base.py", line 111, in _sync
    return task.result()
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_network.py", line 362, in json
    return json.loads(await self.text())
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_network.py", line 358, in text
    content = await self.body()
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_network.py", line 354, in body
    binary = await self._channel.send("body")
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 39, in send
    return await self.inner_send(method, params, False)
  File "/home/avy/anaconda3/envs/Turf/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 63, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Response body is unavailable for redirect responses
{'240': 'https://private4-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/ec808fddd1b10659cb7d3bfeb7cba591/62e9abc8/equidia_2752987/videos/240p_full_mp4/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523-240p_full_mp4.mp4?v=0', '360': 'https://private3-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/7c5cc10f2bb466fd85d7109c698500d3/62e9abc8/equidia_2752987/videos/360p_full_mp4/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523-360p_full_mp4.mp4?v=0', '480': 'https://private3-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/c65277c3e385fb825e0ea4f5c1447d00/62e9abc8/equidia_2752987/videos/480p_full_mp4/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523-480p_full_mp4.mp4?v=0', '540': 'https://private3-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/036f88b63a1157ce51bf68a7e60791cc/62e9abc8/equidia_2752987/videos/540p_full_mp4/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523-540p_full_mp4.mp4?v=0', '720': 'https://private8-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/459a1e569da63e69031d1ecbf1f87ed0/62e9abc8/equidia_2752987/videos/720p_full_mp4/63/03/S506303/V556523/20220731_35186008_00000hr-s506303-v556523-720p_full_mp4.mp4?v=0'}
```

I managed to obtain the piece I wanted but with a lot of exceptions that I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title and sentences. This would be gentle to your readers. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @buhtz There are good reasons to do not show code: 1 -> the video's container is "empty" for the spider. So how could I code on something that does not exist ? I simply cannot go further in the code ! 2. I clearly gave the possibility to check in `scrapy shell` the desired url, so the minimal reproducible example is already present. 3. before my topic was closed once, I precised that I tried [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818249/capturing-the-video-stream-from-a-website-into-a-file) but it does not correspond to my specifications. I already shown my efforts, it was closed..

Comment: Video source is being called via XHR (https://private3-stream-ovp.vide.io/dl/12915b368bdfab5cd34abace319c56d3/62e8fc78/equidia_2752987/videos/hls/63/03/S506303/V556523/s16/s16-00003.ts?v=1). FF extension has access to the full page, including network calls, so it can retrieve the video this way (I guess, I didn;t review source code). In your case... I would use selenium for this job, straight-forward.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire thank you. I did some researches about what you told me, and I made an update. For the moment, I avoid selenium. Have a look if you have time.

Comment: @Alexander the main problem is to obtain the `XHR` request that begins with `equidia-vodce-p-api`. With `pytube` you must know the url adress for the video. It's not a "request finder" as far as I know when I check the [documentation](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fully working solution by using `scrapy-playwright`, I got the idea the following issue [61](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright/issues/61) and the users profile [@lime-n](https://github.com/lime-n/Python-Project/blob/main/Scrapy_playwright-project/infinite_scroll.py).

We download the `xhr` requests sent and store these into a dict with both the `playwright` tools and `scrapy-playwright`. I include the `playwright_page_event_handlers` to integrate `playwright` tools for this.

Depending on the video size, it will take a few minutes to download.

main.py

```
import scrapy
from playwright.async_api import Response as PlaywrightResponse
import jsonlines
import pandas as pd
import json
from video.items import videoItem

headers = {
    'authority': 'api.equidia.fr',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://www.equidia.fr',
    'referer': 'https://www.equidia.fr/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

class videoDownloadSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'video'
    start_urls = ['https://www.equidia.fr/courses/2022-07-31/R1/C1']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url,
                #callback = self.parse, 
                meta = {
                    'playwright':True,
                    'playwright_page_event_handlers':{
                    "response": "handle_response",
                }
                
                }               
            )

    async def handle_response(self, response: PlaywrightResponse) -> None:
        """
        We can grab the post data with response.request.post - there are three different types for different needs.
        The method below helps grab those resource types of 'xhr' and 'fetch' until I can work out how to only send these to the download request.
        """
        self.logger.info(f'test the log of data: {response.request.resource_type, response.request.url, response.request.method}')
        jl_file = "videos.jl"
        data = {}
        if response.request.resource_type == "xhr":
            if response.request.method == "GET":
                if 'videos' in response.request.url:

                    data['resource_type']=response.request.resource_type,
                    data['request_url']=response.request.url,
                    data['method']=response.request.method
                    with jsonlines.open(jl_file, mode='a') as writer:
                        writer.write(data)

    def parse(self, response):
        video = pd.read_json('videos.jl', lines=True)
        print('KEST: %s' % video['request_url'][0][0])

        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            url = video['request_url'][0][0],
            headers=headers,
            callback = self.parse_video_json
        )
    def parse_video_json(self, response):
        another_url = response.json().get('video_url')
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            another_url,
            headers=headers,
            callback=self.extract_videos
        )

    def extract_videos(self, response):
        videos = response.json().get('mp4')
        for keys, vids in videos.items():
            loader = videoItem()
            loader['video'] = [vids]
            yield loader
```

items.py

```
class videoItem(scrapy.Item):
    video = scrapy.Field()
```

pipelines.py

```
class downloadFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, item=None):
        file = request.url.split('/')[-1]
        video_file = f"{file}.mp4"
        return video_file
```

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

FILES_STORE = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'videos')

FILES_URLS_FIELD = 'video'
FILES_RESULT_FIELD = 'results'


DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}

TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'video.pipelines.downloadFilesPipeline': 150,
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am sorry for the time it took to validate your great answer, I was too busy these last weeks. Now, maybe I am not enough attentive: I don't get why you inserted the fields `FILES_URLS_FIELD = 'video'` and `FILES_RESULT_FIELD = 'results'` in the settings of the spider. I don't see where there are references of those fields in the rest of the source code. Moreover, you seem to be an expert in it and good at explaining, so can you orient me to good contents to understand those principle of "async" for a noob about it ?